# SwiftUI Keeping data up to date across views and view models

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I come from a `react-native` background and I am having trouble understanding a specific part of MVVM in SwiftUI: having multiple views of the same entities.

I am building a simple social media app with posts. These posts can be viewed on the `Homepage`, and on the `Profile` page of any user.

This is what the view models look like

```swift
struct HomepagePosts: ObservableObject {
  @Published var posts = [Post]()

  ... rest of logic
}

struct ProfilePosts: ObservableObject {
  @Published var posts = [Post]()

  ... rest of logic
}
```

My problem is the following. If a user just posted a post, that post will show up on the homepage and on his profile. What if the user decides to update the post? How will the post be updated in all places?

In React this is done by normalizing state. Instead of keeping separate `posts` arrays, you keep 2 arrays of `postId`s, and one dictionary with the `postId` as key and the entire `Post` object as the value. That way, updating the post updates it in one place, and every view updates directly.

How do you do this in SwiftUI?

Comment: What is type of Post?

Comment: @mahan simple `struct` with `id` and `content` as properties.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you have 2 ObservableObject and they don't relate to each other.
It would be best to have just one source of "truth" and use that everywhere. For example: "struct PostsModel: ObservableObject". That way you avoid the 
complications of having to constantly sync the two Post arrays in the different ObservableObject.

Comment: @workingdog yes, one source of truth is what I want. However, if I have `PostsModel` struct, where do I keep the arrays of posts for the homepage and profile? -- also, the 2 objects do relate to each other. They are different "post feeds" that can contain the same post in either

Comment: I usually have a StorageManager that the ViewModels reference. to keep all the objects in one source of truth. Also, recently I was [introduced to VIPER](https://medium.com/@smalam119/viper-design-pattern-for-ios-application-development-7a9703902af6) and I think this pattern would be quite helpful when you need the UI updated by an external source.

Comment: so in essence, the 2 arrays of Posts are the same, but are "updated/obtained" from different feeds. If that's correct, then keep only 1 Post array in one ObservableObject, say StorageManager.

Comment: Keep the state of things (in this case posts) in one ObservableObject (only one, not one for each View). Then any View that depends on posts (such as Homepage and Profile) will reference that one object  (as an ObservedObject or probably cleaner EnvironmentObject). Any change to posts will cause those views to refresh automatically (forget MVVM and Viper).  Other properties can be added to the model or make a separate model if you want. Finally, Post itself can be a struct, but the model holding it can't, since `ObservableObjects` must be class with a reference. What you have can't compile.

Comment: Not sure why these responses were missing the main point. I found it very clear what @DariusMandres was explaining as I'm having the same issue. Did you find an elegant solution for this? I've managed to get it working but by having one giant model instead of being able to break down into individual viewModels which I'm not a fan of

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to illustrate the comment above. I believe you want to structure it something like this, with only one model object.

```
struct Post: Identifiable {
  let id: String
  let text: String
}

class Model: ObservableObject {
  @Published var posts: [Post] = []
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
  // @StateObject var model = Model()
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      Homepage()
       // .environmentObject(model)
    }
  }
}

struct Homepage: View {
  // @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
  @StateObject var model = Model() // holds array of homepage posts
  @State private var newPost: String = ""
  @State private var showProfile = false
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("new post", text: $newPost) { _ in
      } onCommit: {
        model.posts.append(Post(id: UUID().uuidString, text: newPost))
        newPost = ""
      }
      Divider()
      ScrollView {
        ForEach(model.posts) { post in
          Text(post.text).padding()
        }
      }
      Divider()
      Button("Profile") {
        showProfile = true
      }
      .sheet(isPresented: $showProfile) {
        Profile()
      }
    }
    .padding()
  }
}

struct Profile: View {
  // @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
  @StateObject var model = Model() // holds array of profile posts
  var body: some View {
    Text("You have \(model.posts.count) posts")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't account for the case where `homepagePosts` and `profilePosts` can have different posts in them, with only a few posts overlapping. How would that fit into this?

Comment: In that case you do need two different objects, both would be of type Model though. I've commented out and added the changes. @mahan is right though, if you want them to be synced, why make them different?

Comment: So this is ideally what I want, but my last question is if `Post 1` is found in both the homepage and the profile, and the user edits it from their profile, will that edit be reflected in homepage automatically? Because that's what I want

Comment: Yes, because they both refer to the same single source of data (if you use the first version). SwiftUI will handle refreshing the View when the state of that data changes.

Comment: But if I use the first version, I will then lose the ability to have 2 separate arrays of Posts independent of each other no? In version 2 I can have the separate arrays, but it seems I cannot sync one post in both arrays. Is there no way to have both?

Comment: When you say synced, what do you mean exactly. Just synced means they will be exactly the same, but you want them to be different? Do you mean they start different and new posts are added to both? or it only syncs one-way? or something else

Comment: If the post text gets updated on the profile, I want that same post in the homepage (if it is there) to receive the update automatically. Think of it like any social media. You have your own posts on your profile, and you can also see your post and others  in your home feed. That's 2 different arrays of posts, with their own independent pagination states, displaying the same entity `Post`, with overlaps allowed. That's all I really want to accomplish.

Comment: You could keep two different sets of posts and merge them as you want. But it would be easier to maintain one universal set of posts, I think. Just add a `user` property to `Post` that identifies the user that posted it. Then in the profile page filter only the posts that match you as the user.

Comment: In React there's an easy solution for this. Normalize the state, keep one copy of every full `Post` entity, and only keep arrays of reference IDs everywhere else. I've resorted to doing my own implementation of that.

Answer (score 0):

`struct` can not confirm to the `ObservableObject` protocol. Only `class` can do so. Therefore,  `HomepagePosts` and `ProfilePosts` have to be of type `class`.

---

You do not have to make two difference classes for posts. Use a single `ObservableObject` for the data shared between the views.

```
struct Post: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let content: String
}

class PostModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
}
```

Pass a single instance of `PostModel` to both `HomepagePosts` and `ProfilePosts`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var postModel: PostModel = PostModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ProfilePostsView(postModel: postModel)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Profile", systemImage: "person")
                }
            
            HomepageView(postModel: postModel)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

---

All the code ready for test.

```
struct Post: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let content: String
}

class PostModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var postModel: PostModel = PostModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ProfilePostsView(postModel: postModel)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Profile", systemImage: "person")
                }
            
            HomepageView(postModel: postModel)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
        }
    }
}



struct ProfilePostsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var postModel: PostModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(postModel.posts) { post in
                    Text(post.content)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct HomepageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var postModel: PostModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.postModel.posts.append(Post(content: "Hello \(Date())"))
                }, label: {
                    Text("Add new Posts")
                })
                List(postModel.posts) { post in
                    Text( post.content)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, if you add new posts in `HomepageView`, the same posts are automatically added in the second tab (`ProfilePostsView`). They will be updated if you do so.

---

`postModel` can also be a property of `HomepagePosts` and `ProfilePosts`.

#### More info:

---

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

*Note: this approach is similar to **Cenk Bilgen***

Comment: This looks great, thanks a lot. One question that I think affects a little here. `homepage` and `profile` posts do not have to always be identical. They can have overlaps of posts, but must be independent. How do you structure it to sync a post that happens to be in both?

Comment: This is clearly not a good approach if posts overlap. Recommend you to update your question. Someone might answer.  @DariusMandres

Comment: Well yeah, I'm building a social media app where there are many different feeds of posts with different pagination states, but one post can be found in any feed at any time and it needs to be synched. I think this is a pretty normal use case yet I cannot find one proper solution on how to structure that